# Parsing terraform output in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, terraform, jenkins-pipeline

I have this Jenkins file:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'vmNames', defaultValue: 'host-01,host-02,host-03', description: 'Enter VM names (comma-separated)')
        string(name: 'xoaUrl', defaultValue: 'wss://xo.example.com', description: 'Enter XOA URL' )
        string(name: 'xoaUser', defaultValue: 'red.crick', description: 'Enter XOA User' )
    }

    environment {
        TERRAFORM_HOME = tool name: 'terraform', type: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation'
        PATH = "${TERRAFORM_HOME}:${env.PATH}"
        XOA_URL = "${xoaUrl}"
        XOA_USER = "${xoaUser}"
        XOA_PASSWORD = "${xoaPassword}"
    }

    stages {
        stage("Terraform init") {        
        ...
        }

        stage("Terraform plan") {
        ...
        }

        stage("Terraform apply") {
            steps {
                dir('dev/xo/clusters/sandbox') {
                    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'XOA_PASSWORD', variable: 'xoaPassword')]) {
                        sh '''
                        export XOA_PASSWORD="${xoaPassword}"
                        terraform apply -parallelism=1 -no-color "theplan"
                        '''
                        script {
                            def output = sh(script: 'terraform output -json', returnStdout: true).trim()
                            echo "output is $output"

                            def ipAddresses = readJSON(text: output).ip_addresses.value
                            echo "ipAddresses is $ipAddresses"
                            echo "ipAddresses[0] is $ipAddresses[0]"

                            currentBuild.description = jsonArray.collect { JSONArray.fromObject(ipAddresses) }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Set Hostname and Reboot to Get DNS Records Created.") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def ipAddresses = currentBuild.description
                    def hostnames = vmNames.split(',')

                    withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'bpadmin-private-ssh-key', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_PRIVATE_KEY', usernameVariable: 'USER')]) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ipAddresses.size(); i++) {
                            def ipAddress = ipAddresses[i].trim()
                            def hostname = hostnames[i].trim() // Access the correct hostname using the index

                            echo "Setting hostname $hostname for IP address $ipAddress"                    
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I do not know how to handle the variable `def ipAddresses = readJSON(text: output).ip_addresses.value`.  Is it a list? Is it a string? What I was hoping for was output that would look something like this:

```
Setting hostname host-01 for IP address 10.0.22.1
Setting hostname host-02 for IP address 10.0.22.6
Setting hostname host-03 for IP address 10.0.22.16
...
```

But I get this error:

```
ipAddresses is [[10.0.253.236], [10.0.253.234], [10.0.253.233], [10.0.253.231], [10.0.253.232], [10.0.253.235]]
[Pipeline] echo
ipAddresses[0] is [[10.0.253.236], [10.0.253.234], [10.0.253.233], [10.0.253.231], [10.0.253.232], [10.0.253.235]][0]
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Set Hostname and Reboot to Get DNS Records Created.)
Stage "Set Hostname and Reboot to Get DNS Records Created." skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 841a0fee-7b3b-404b-b647-717c38019255
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jsonArray for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:285)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:375)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, the `ipAddresses` variable looks to be an instance of `JSONArray`, so you could just add

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray
```

at the top of your pipeline to fix that error message.

But you don't have to. `JSONArray` is also a `List`, so just treat it as any other groovy list.

```
currentBuild.description = ipAddresses.flatten().join(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

`ipAddresses` is a `List<List<String>>` where each nested List contains the ip address element you are attempting to access. We can flatten this list and then iterate through it to accomplish your goal:

```
List ipAddresses = readJSON(text: output).ip_addresses.value
List hostnames = vmNames.split(',')

ipAddresses.flatten().eachWithIndex { ipAddress, i ->
  echo "Setting hostname ${hostname[i].trim()} for IP address ${ipAddress}"
}
```

Note that the above string interpolation syntax is safer (ergo why your `$ipAddresses[0]` produced an unexpected result as it should be `${ipAddresses[0]}`), and I also see no information about the definition of `vmNames` in the question, and so I have omitted it from the answer, and will need to assume it is already treated correctly. However, I would recommend associating the definition and/or data of `vmNames` with the ip addresses somehow to more safely ensure the two are accurate.